# Buffering update not reaching 100% in seek bar attached with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, seekbar, buffering

Here I have developed an app which does streaming of audio file stored in a server.
This is done using `MediaPlayer` class. The current playback position and buffering level of song is shown in a custom `Seekbar`. 
So far I have managed to show the buffering progress as secondary progress in seekbar, synchronize the primary progress of seekbar with MediaPlayer playback, and play,pause and stop the playback on respective button clicks.
But now I am stuck with the problem of buffering progress not showing greater than around 86 to 89 percent and same is reflected in seekbar secondary progress i.e. buffering progress in seekbar does not increase after (86-89 percent) .I have captured the buffering percentage in the log and attaching the relevant log details below.

```
07-02 14:21:34.484 14537-14559/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/MediaPlayer: prepared
07-02 14:21:34.484 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
07-02 14:21:34.494 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 366 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 14:21:34.514 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
07-02 14:21:34.544 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 5
07-02 14:21:35.524 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 8
07-02 14:21:36.524 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 15
07-02 14:21:37.524 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 29
07-02 14:21:38.524 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 43
07-02 14:21:39.524 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 59
07-02 14:21:40.524 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 75
07-02 14:21:41.524 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 89
07-02 14:22:31.034 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
07-02 14:22:31.034 14537-14710/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp D/MediaHTTPConnection: filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val= stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.1.1)
07-02 14:22:31.034 14537-14559/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp D/MediaHTTPConnection: proxy null port 0
07-02 14:22:33.554 14537-14559/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp D/MediaHTTPConnection: mTotalSize_1=4673664
    mTotalSize_2=4673664
07-02 14:22:37.004 14537-14560/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/MediaPlayer: prepared
07-02 14:22:37.004 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
07-02 14:22:37.004 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 357 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 14:22:37.034 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
07-02 14:22:37.054 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 3
07-02 14:22:38.034 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 6
07-02 14:22:39.034 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 10
07-02 14:22:40.034 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 17
07-02 14:22:41.034 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 27
07-02 14:22:42.044 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 40
07-02 14:22:43.044 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 56
07-02 14:22:44.044 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 70
07-02 14:22:45.044 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp I/Buffering: 86
07-02 14:22:49.914 14537-14537/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp D/yuan: onVisibilityChanged----android.widget.ListView{2b9dfca7 VFED.VC. .F...... 20,83-700,1066 #7f040024 app:id/list}
07-02 14:22:55.004 14537-14555/com.appy.unofficialsultanapp W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

I am also attaching the screenshot of buffered level of the song in seekbar, highlighted with red.[image: Screenshot of buffered level]
I have done a great deal of research on web to search for its reason and solutions, but none of them worked for me.Even though when seekbar is dragged to a position ahead of buffered song position(white strip in screenshot)) after around 86%, song plays without any issue, but secondary progress gets stuck before that as shown in screenshot.
Here is the code which does overall interaction between `MediaPlayer` and `SeekBar`

*Code snippet from Songs class created in Songs.java*

```
private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {         /**method to update 
primary progress of seekbar**/
    seekBar.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 
mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds) * 100));
    tvElapsedTime.setText(getTimeString(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {         /**onClick event handler to handle 
play, pause and stop button clicks for mediaplayer **/
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonPlay) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            imPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonPause) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        imPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonStop) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(0);
            imPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonPlay && !itemClicked) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please touch a song to start 
playing it.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {   
    if (v.getId() == R.id.seekBar) {
        /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to 
seekBar primary progress position*/
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
            int playPositionInMilliseconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 
    100) * sb.getProgress();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMilliseconds);

tvElapsedTime.setText(getTimeString(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public String getTimeString(long millis) {     /**method to convert passed 
milliseconds to minutes and seconds and return in form of string**/
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    int mins = (int) ((millis % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    int secs = (int) (((millis % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    buf.append(String.format("%02d", mins)).append(":")
            .append(String.format("%02d", secs));
    return buf.toString();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

> Below is the code snippet of same class when listitem i.e any song is clicked

```
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final 
            int position, long id) {
                list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                url = songdetails.get(position).getUrl(); // your URl

                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                }

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // create instance of 
mediaplayer here
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    itemClicked = true;

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration();// 
gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new 
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                        imPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        imPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();

tvEndTime.setText(getTimeString(mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds));
                        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new 
MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int 
percent) {
                                if (percent < seekBar.getMax()) {
                                    seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);  
/** This is the point where secondary progress is set on buffering update **/
                                    Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);   /** 
and this is the point where tat buffered percentage is captured in logcat **/
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new 
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
            }
        });
```

So my buffering progress is not reaching to 100% as I expect it to do.

Comment: Try change: `percent < seekBar.getMax()` to `percent <= seekBar.getMax()` Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello @Divya, did you resolve this issue?
I am facing same issue while playing song.
Please help me to out from this issue.

Comment: @PrashantGosai yes I have resolved it. But I have forgotten the change as it is a very old question and resolved long time back. But, will go through my code soon and will get back to you with the solution.

Comment: @PrashantGosai can you describe what issue you are facing while playing the song?

Comment: @DivyaGupta Thanks for asking, client's meditation app where client upload its audio on server and we fetch it in android via url and load it to media player, but some how audio load only 80% and stop buffering over there, so stuck over here

Comment: @PrashantGosai Okay then, I will look into my code changes in around 1-2 days and will share the working code snippet here.

Comment: @PrashantGosai I have created a gist for your reference in case you like to go through the code snippet of working `SeekBar` of mine. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Divya0319/b414556bad77fecbfbfca94820afcacc#file-seekbarprogresssnippet-java) is the link to that gist.

Comment: @PrashantGosai did it help?